# Elements sum rule for special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Consider the following matrix.

[image]

From the matrix, it's obvious that the sum of the **black** part ($S_1$) and the sum of the **red** part ($S_2$) are

$$S_1 := {\sum_{i=1}^{5}}(6-i)a_i, \qquad S_2:= {\sum_{i=1}^{5}}(i-1)a_i$$

respectively. Suppose that I know $M := {\sum_{i=1}^{5}}a_i$. Can i use the structure of the given matrix to find the values of $S_1$ and $S_2$ in terms of $M$ only?

From the matrix i can tell that $S_1+S_2=5M$. With another solution we can write $S_1$ and $S_2$ in terms of $M$ only. So are there any rules or theory that can help doing that? and could it work for any dimension $N$ of the given matrix? Please someone help me guys. Thank you guys so much and thanks for such great platform!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're looking for. Interchanging any two of the $a_i$ (with different values) fixes $M$ but typically changes $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: @TravisWillse i want $S_1$ and $S_2$ in terms of $M$

Comment: @A.M.MElsayed马克 You don't need a 2nd solution, you need a 2nd measurement

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo what it could be?

Comment: @A.M.MElsayed马克 Anything other than a multiple of the sum of the $a_i$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo i didn't understand

Comment: @A.M.MElsayed马克 You have a system of 2 linear equations in 5 unknowns. You have 3 degrees of freedom

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo i don't look at $a_i$, i just look at $S_{1,2}$ and $M$

Comment: @A.M.MElsayed马克 Exactly, the $a_i$ are unknown. The solution set is a 3-dimensional subspace in 5-dimensional space.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo So is there someway we can write $S_{1,2}$ in terms of $M$?

Comment: @A.M.MElsayed马克 You already did.  Unfortunately, you only have one equation

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo do you think we can find another equation?

Comment: @A.M.MElsayed马克 You do!  However, not in terms of $M$. If you stuck to conventions, you would not be as confused

Answer (score 1):

Once you have defined $S_1$, $S_2$ and $M$, you can forget the fact that you have a matrix. It will not give you any more structure.

Now, Rodrigo is right in that your system of equations are *underdetermined*, i.e. you do not have enough information to guarantee a unique solution. The degrees of freedom may not be $3$, however, since you are not after all the $a_i$'s, just $S_1$ and $S_2$. In any case, let me give you an example to show that you *cannot* determine $S_1$ and $S_2$ from $M$:

Take first $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_5=1$. Then $M=5$, $S_1=15$ and $S_2=10$. However, if we take $a_1=\dots=a_4 = 0$ and $a_5=5$, we still get $M=5$, but $S_1=5$ and $S_2=20$. As you can see, both cases satisfy $S_1+S_2=5M$, but the $S_1$ and $S_2$ can vary anyway even for a fixed $M$.